# Trigger ng-click function on page load

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to take a function that is called by an ng-click event and have it trigger automatically when the page has finished loading in its default state.

```
<li ng-repeat="region in regionBounds">
    <a title="{{region.region}}" ng-click="gotoRegion(region.region)">
        <span>{{region.region}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I don't understand how to get to this function and call it, but here is how the function is defined in the original script...

```
angular.module("smartwayTraffic").controller("mapController", ["$scope", "$window", "$q", "$timeout", "$modal", "_", "constant", "geolocation", "dataService", "mapService", function(n, t, i, r, u, f, e, o, s, h) {

...

    n.gotoRegion = function(t) {
        e.regionBounds.forEach(function(i) {
            i.region === t && (y(), n.map.control.fitBounds(i.bounds), v())
        })
    };

....
```

The goal of this project is to automate the loading of a certain view of an existing traffic website, take a screenshot, and send it off. I have everything else in place to load the the page, take the shot, and send it off, but there is no way to bookmark the different areas and have them load automatically.

Thanks

Comment: So you want it to have a default value? Why not just call the function after it has been defined with a basic value?

Comment: I have four values to pass into the function that the site has defined. They are Nashville, Chattanooga, Knoxville, and Memphis. I am thinking that if I pass in one of these values into gotoRegion(), it will setup the map on it's own from there.

Comment: use ng-init on view or $timeout(function(){functioName()});

Comment: I'm not sure how Angular works, but I have been trying to just call the function in the console with one of these values to see if it sets everything up. The main issue might be that I don't know how the scope works when accessing controller functions.